# Unable to create machine image from VM instance in gcp

Tags: google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine

I am unable to create machine image from the existing vm instance in gcp. It shows following error as shown in the image attached link.could anyone help to create a machine image. I did set the project using set project command. [gcp machine image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R2ti4.jpg)

Comment: SO is a programming Q&A platform and this question is not about programming. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Please delete this.

Comment: It tells you what the error is.  Look at the `gcloud compute machine-images create` command documentation

Answer (score 1):

The command does not have the command flag `--zone`. Replace with the flag `--source-instance-zone`.

[gcloud compute machine-images create](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/machine-images/create)